# how to know which activity is calling custom list adapter?

Tags: android, listview, adapter

Basically what I want to do is: I have a listview with custom list adapter in my application. But I want to change a TextLabel based on the calling activity of the adapter. I have three lists in activity like Product list,Favorites and History. So is there any way that we can get calling(parentActivity)?

Easy solution is design different layouts for all lists but I don't want that kind of redundant code.

customListAdapter:

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private final Context context;
private  ArrayList<Product> products=new ArrayList<>() ;

public CustomListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Product> product) {


    this.context=context;
    this.products=product;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return products.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_list_item, null, true);

    TextView title = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.product_title);
    //TextView url = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.product_url);
    TextView createDate = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.product_create_date);
    ImageView icon=(ImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageArrow);


  ...........
    title.setText(productInfo.getTitle());

    createDate.setText("Created Date: "+productInfo.getCreatedDate());
    icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.go_right);
    return rowView;

};
}
```

So I want to change created date with modified date for history list.

Comment: Please show code of your adapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call your adapter you pass the activity context. You can use that to identify the calling activity like this

**Solution 1**

```
String currentActivity = this.context.getClass().getName();
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(currentActivity)) { 
    if(currentActivity.contains("com.example.activity1")){
        // do this
    }
    else if(currentActivity.contains("com.example.activity2")){
        // do that
    }
}
```

**Solution 2**

```
if(this.context instanceof Activity1){
    // do this
}
else if(this.context instanceof Activity2){
    // do that
}
```

**Note:** This is how you should be calling your adapter

```
CustomListAdapter myCustomListAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, myProducts); // In activity
```

or

```
CustomListAdapter myCustomListAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), myProducts); // In Fragment
```